# How to add empty spaces after custom listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

**My problem,**

In my custom listview last element 'select' button overlap with cart icon.

**My question,**

How to add some empty space after end of custom listview?

Comment: Put more top and bottom padding for item view

Comment: is your question complete? how would even an expert developer understand your question?

Answer (score 1):

you can set Linear layout for your listview. And you can use another linear layout for your footer(Cart icon).

when you setting up linear layouts, you can add layour weights ,so that you can arrange your listview and cart icon clearly.

if you want more clarifications inform me